# Post to Google Groups via email

Tags: google-groups

OK, so my task is simple: I want to post a message on Google Groups.

It *appears* that you're supposed to be able to sign up by sending a blank email to `foobar+subscribe@googlegroups.com`. I did this, and got a confirmation email. I clicked the link, which took me to a CAPTCHA on the web interface. I filled that in, and received *another* confirmation email. I clicked the link on that, and the web interface seemed to indicate that I'm subscribed now.

So... how do I send an email? I would have *thought* that simply sending a message to `foobar@googlegroups.com` would do it. But I sent a test message over an hour ago, and I still can't see it through the web interface. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you seeing your message on the group's page? Does the group allow members to send messages?

Comment: Given that it's a user support group, I would _imagine_ that posting is allowed...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a group owner I can tell you that it is possible that your subscription and/or your message are awaiting confirmation from the group managers. Some groups do not allow new users posting rights until they are conformed.
Another possibility is that the group doesn't allow members to send messages.

My recommendation is to wait a bit longer (until a moderator checks his/her email). Or attempt to contact the owner/moderator to ask for more information.

Comment: A day later, my test message hasn't appeared, but several messages from the group have been delivered to me. However, I just sent my _real_ message, and it appeared on the web page within seconds. Spam filter? IDK.

Comment: ...and now the test message has appeared as well. So yes, it seems it was just held for moderation.